# Connecting to postgres database generated from docker-compose yaml

Tags: postgresql, docker

EDIT: The docker-compose file creates a prisma instance just fine, and this can talk to the database, but I also want to be able to connect to the database from my mac on the command line as if it was a local database.

I'm using docker-compose to create a prisma api connected to a postgres container. This works fine, but I can't access the postgres instance without entering the container first, even though I thought I'd set up port forwarding. This is my docker-compose yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.13
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4040:4040"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4040
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

When I look at `docker ps` it has `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp` in the ports column for the postgres container, but when I try any of

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U prisma
psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -U prisma
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U prisma
```

I get errors saying prisma is not a role. When I try the same thing with `-U postgres` I can get into the database, but the prisma database doesn't exist (but it does in the container).

I've done a lot of googling but haven't found any solution, so would be very happy if someone could explain where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer so people know not to bother - I restarted my brew service of postgresql and then it just worked...weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding, under 'prisma', it will make sure to wait for database to startup:

```
depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Maybe your database container is not up yet when 'prisma' container trying to connect.

Comment: Thanks Romas, I added an edit to this question because I think I was unclear, but the issue isn't with the prisma instance (that works fine) I just also want to be able to connect to the database from the command line on my mac. Do you know how to do that?